# converting nanosec to microsecond

Tags: c, multithreading

I am using the below code to convert nano to micro sec

This code runs fines mostly but some times I see the usTick gives a value far beyond the current time.

For ex. if the current time in usTick is 63290061063 then sometimes this value is coming as 126580061060. If you see it is double.

Similarly one more instance I got is current time is 45960787154, but the usTick is showing as 91920787152

```
typedef unsigned long long TUINT64 
unsigned long long GetMonoUSTick()
{
    static unsigned long long usTick;
    struct        timespec t;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t);
    usTick  =  ((TUINT64)t.tv_nsec) / 1000;
    usTick  =  usTick +((TUINT64)t.tv_sec) * 1000000;
    return usTick;
}
```

Comment: Why not get the nanoseconds into the long long before attempting any calculations?  Is the long long not long enough?

Comment: A `unsigned long long` is guaranteed able to represent values up to `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`.    With the values described, and assuming `TUINT64` hold a similar range, overflow is unlikely.   Anyway, voting to close since no question has been asked, and the intent is unclear.

Comment: typecasted it to unsigned long long, should be ok, i guess. Do you see any issue here ?

Comment: Peter, I have asked the question, please read. The usTick is not coming correct sometines.

Comment: What is "the current tick" whose value is `45960787154`? You convert *two* values (`tv_nsec` and `tv_sec`) to `usTick`, neither of which is called "current tick". Very confusing.

Comment: Sidenote: There are standard txpes like `uint64_t`, why not use this one?

Comment: Why is `usTick` defined `static`?

Comment: current tick is nothing but the current time.

Comment: This is an existing code, I am debugging some issue here. I also didn't get why static is used here, but don't see that it can cause any harm

Comment: You also should check the return value `clock_gettime()`

Comment: @Anu: this code can not work, at least not with the missing `;`

Comment: There is a `;` missing after the definition of `TUINT64`.

Comment: @alk- not expecting these kind of comments on this site. That is copy paste mistake

Comment: Is this code running in a single- or in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. without copy-paste errors.

Comment: 'not expecting these kind of comments on this site. That is copy paste mistake' - really?  You are wasting everyone's time with such 'mistakes'.  Reload/update/fix your OS shell so that it does not make mistakes with its clipboard, that, or you should apologise to @Anu etc. for taking out your mistakes on them :(

Answer (score 1):

If multiple threads of the same process in parallel access variables concurrently for reading/writing or writing/writing those variables need to protected. This can be achieved by using a mutex.

In this case the local variable `usTick` needs to be protected as it is defined `static`.

Using POSIX-threads the code could look like this:

```
  pthread_mutex_lock(&ustick_mutex);

  usTick  =  ((TUINT64)t.tv_nsec) / 1000;
  usTick  =  usTick +((TUINT64)t.tv_sec) * 1000000;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&ustick_mutex);
```

<sup>*(error checking left out for clarity)*</sup>

Take care to initialise `ustick_mutex` properly before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using threads and that once in a while two threads are calling this function at the same time. Because `usTick` is `static`, they are working with the same variable (not two different copies). They both convert the nanoseconds to microseconds and assign to `usTick`, one after the other, and then they both convert the seconds to microseconds and both add them to `usTick` (so the seconds get added twice).

EDIT - The following solution I proposed was based on two assumption:

- If two threats called the function at the same time, the difference between the current time returned by `clock_gettime()` would be too small to matter (the difference between the results calculated by the threads would at most be `1`).
- On most modern CPU's, reading/writing an integer is an atomic operation.

<del>I think you should be able to fix this by changing:</del>

<del>`usTick  =  ((TUINT64)t.tv_nsec) / 1000;`</del>
<del>`usTick  =  usTick +((TUINT64)t.tv_sec) * 1000000;`</del>

<del>to:</del>

<del>`usTick  =  ((TUINT64)t.tv_nsec) / 1000 + ((TUINT64)t.tv_sec) * 1000000;`</del>

The problem with my solution was that even if the later assumption would be correct, it might not hold for `long long`. Therefore, for example this could happen:

- Thread A and B call the function at (almost) the same time.
- Thread A calculates current time in microsecond as `0x02B3 1F02 FFFF FFFF`.
- Thread B calculates current time in microsecond as `0x02B3 1F03 0000 0000`.
- Thread A writes the least significant 32 bits (`0xFFFF FFFF`) to `usTick`.
- Thread B writes the least significant 32 bits (`0x0000 0000`) to `usTick`.
- Thread B writes the most significant 32 bits (`0x02B3 1F03`)to `usTick`.
- Thread A writes the most significant 32 bits (`0x02B3 1F02`)to `usTick`.

and then the function would in both threads return `0x02B3 1F02 0000 0000` which is off by `4294967295`.

So do as @alk said, use mutex to protect the read/write of `usTick`

Comment: SiggiSv- Thanks a lot. Yes we are using threads, and two threads can use this function. Again thanks a lot

Comment: If used concurrently your second version would not help (a lot). Concurrent read/write (write/write) access to `usTick` ***has to be*** protected. This for example can be achieved by using a mutex.

Comment: So your diagnose is correct, the proposed the solution isn't.

Comment: @alk You're right. I haven't been using threads recently so I remembered enough to see the problem but not enough to give a correct solution to the problem. My proposed solution was based on two assumption: a) if two threats called the function at the same time, the difference between the current time returned by `clock_gettime()` would be too small to matter. b) on most modern CPU's, reading/writing an integer is an atomic operation (but even if that would be correct, it might not hold for `long long`). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys for the solutions proposed.Will take care and test it. Thanks again.